Issues with `requests` between Python versions
I'm currently working on some issues on a project not developed by me, investpy.
In the search.py file, at line 157 (function search_quotes), I get a ConnectionError (not raised by requests, but connected to the status_code returned by requests).
This error is weirdly only raised on Python 3.11, while Python 3.10 works without issue.
I've edited the code in order to print some important informations (the parameters and the output for the requests's POST function).
Snippet (original, can be found at the link before):
req = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=params)

if req.status_code != 200:
    raise ConnectionError(
        f"ERR#0015: error {req.status_code}, try again later."
    )

data = req.json()

Snippet (modified, added print statements and a static user agent, while the original project generated each time a new user agent in order to fake activity):
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.5; en-US; rv:1.9.1b3) Gecko/20090305 Firefox/3.1b3 GTB5', 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', 'Accept': 'text/html', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
print(params)
print("---")
print(headers)
req = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=params)
print("---")
print(req)

if req.status_code != 200:
  raise ConnectionError(
      f"ERR#0015: error {req.status_code}, try again later."
  )

data = req.json()

Result on CPython 3.10:
>>> investsearch.search_quotes("IBM")
{'search_text': 'IBM', 'tab': 'quotes', 'isFilter': True, 'limit': 270, 'offset': 0}
---
{'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.5; en-US; rv:1.9.1b3) Gecko/20090305 Firefox/3.1b3 GTB5', 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', 'Accept': 'text/html', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
---
<Response [200]>
(LONG ARRAY WITH THE CORRECT DATA)

Results on CPython 3.11:
>>> investsearch.search_quotes("IBM")
{'search_text': 'IBM', 'tab': 'quotes', 'isFilter': True, 'limit': 270, 'offset': 0}
---
{'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.5; en-US; rv:1.9.1b3) Gecko/20090305 Firefox/3.1b3 GTB5', 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', 'Accept': 'text/html', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
---
<Response [403]>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/giuseppe/project_348/Financials-Extension/investpy/investpy/search.py", line 166, in search_quotes
    raise ConnectionError(
ConnectionError: ERR#0015: error 403, try again later.

I'm running the same version of the Request library on both versions of CPython.
Are there any solutions?
Thanks in advance.

The issue is not an issue with the search file. You received a HTTP 403 Forbidden Response. Does the website require authentication?

No, the website doesn't require authentication; but how can a server forbid the request from Python 3.11 and not Python 3.10, using the same code and the same version of Requests, and as printed out in the console, the same headers+parameters)?

You're scraping off the Investing.com website. On the package README, they note that it isn't working correctly, which was over 2 years ago. It could be a compatibility issue in that case. Why is it important to use Python 3.11?

1] Yes, the library itself isn't working as of right now, but my workaround it works on 3.10 so I want to make a PR / fork
2] At the start I wasn't working on this library, but on a LibreOffice extension for using financial data and I'm working on adding Invensting.com. LibreOffice comes with CPython bundled and I can import whatever modules I want from the standard PYTHONPATH, but each version of LO comes with a specific version of CPython and the last stable LO version uses 3.11.9

Weirdly enough, It's now working on Python 3.11 if I downgrade requests to 2.31.0; the workaround requires more tries in order to get the request to be accepted, but it works.
This might be a library issue.

i don't think it will help your 403 issue but if you're simulating an xhr request, you should send your data as json instead of a dict, like req = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=params)
